# How to set delay before project start in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with some projects. I run them with "Multiple startup option". I need that one project starting with 1-2 seconds delay. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: 1. why do you want it to wait 2 seconds? 2. should it build after another project?<br>
If so you could use the Project Depencies. 3. otherwise: set this thread to sleep

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

in Program.cs of the project which should start up delayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onstartup and put the thread to sleep.